# iOS - NSArray indexOfObject does not call customized isEqual

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a people class that override the isEqual method:

```
#import "People.h"

@implementation People
@synthesize name = _name;


-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
    NSLog(@"A.isEqual called");

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        NSString *name = object;
        return [self.name isEqualToString:name];
    }
    return [super isEqual:object];
}

@end
```

When I find people in an array, it doesn't call isEqual method:

```
People* p1 = [People new];
        p1.name = @"A";

        People* p2 = [People new];
        p2.name = @"B";

        NSArray* peopleArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:p1, p2, nil];

        NSLog(@"find A %ld", [peopleArray indexOfObject:@"A"]);

        NSLog(@"isEqual A -> %@", [p1 isEqual:@"A"] ? @"Yes" : @"No");
```

Here is the output:

```
2013-04-10 18:15:47.988 runone[6273:303] find A 9223372036854775807
2013-04-10 18:15:47.988 runone[6273:303] A.isEqual called
2013-04-10 18:15:47.989 runone[6273:303] isEqual A -> Yes
```

Do you know why's that?

Comment: do you have declare in .h?

Comment: declare there, and your method will get called.

Comment: It didn't call either. I think kovpas is right, let see his answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though Apple's docs [says](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) that `isEqual:` is sent to every object in array, it does the other way around - sends `isEqual:` to the object you are searching for.

Since it's assumed that `[a isEqual:b] == [b isEqual:a]`, it shouldn't make any difference in most cases, but in your case it makes.

Here's an example:

```
People* p1 = [People new];
p1.name = @"A";

People* p2 = [People new];
p2.name = @"B";

People* p3 = [People new];
p3.name = @"C";

NSArray* peopleArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:p1, p2, p3, nil];

NSLog(@"find A %ld", (unsigned long)[peopleArray indexOfObject:p3]);
```

And in People's isEqual method:

```
-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    NSLog(@"A.isEqual called %@", [self name]);
    ...
}
```

Output:

```
A.isEqual called C
A.isEqual called C
find A 2
```

Comment: This is correct. The array's implementation will call NSString's isEqual: method, passing in each Person. This will always return NO because they are different types. People and NSString equality is therefore not symmetric. You also need to define -hash if you define isEqual:, even if NSArray doesn't currently call it.

Comment: It would be nice if Apple's documentation was correct! I chased my tail on this quite a while.

Answer (score 4):

If `a == b`, then `b == a`.

Or, in terms of Objective-C, if `[a isEqual:b]`, then **`[b isEqual:a]`** must **also be true**.

Your `-isEqual:` violates that rule.

How `NSArray` uses the `isEqual:` methods is entirely an implementation detail beyond that *`isEqual:` will be used for containment tests*.

Comment: I don't agree with that at all, it's not a containment issue.  Apple's documentation explicitly states the opposite of the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As kovpas's answer, I change isEqual method to adapt with the new idea:

```
#import "People.h"

@implementation People
@synthesize name = _name, age = _age;


-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
    NSLog(@"A.isEqual called");

    if ([object isKindOfClass:self.class]) {
        People *p = object;
        return [self.name isEqualToString:p.name];
    }
    return [super isEqual:object];
}

@end
```

Then add desired String to compare into a people

```
        People* p1 = [People new];
        p1.name = @"A";

        People* p2 = [People new];
        p2.name = @"B";

        NSArray* peopleArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:p1, p2, nil];

        People* p3 = [People new];
        p3.name = @"A";

        NSLog(@"find A %ld", [peopleArray indexOfObject:p3]);
```

It will work like a charm :)

```
2013-04-11 10:28:55.659 runone[1029:303] A.isEqual called
2013-04-11 10:28:55.659 runone[1029:303] find A 0
```